# how to write VALUES statement in a insert statement in Python?

Tags: python, sql

script where I am reading from csv file and iterating all the rows in the csv file but i need help to generate insert statements of each row and I am also output it that into a file. So my only issue is the generate insert statements of each row. Thanks for the help.

here is my code:

```
import csv
openFile = open('data.csv', 'r')
csvFile = csv.reader(openFile)
header = next(csvFile)
headers = map((lambda x: '"' + x + '"'), header)
insert = 'INSERT INTO my_table (' + ", ".join(headers) + ") VALUES "
values = []
for row in csvFile:
     #this line below
     values.append('(' + ','.join(map(lambda x: '"%s"' % x, row)) + ')')
     data = insert + ("".join(values))
print(data)
createOnFile = open("data.txt","w+")
createOnFile.write(data)
createOnFile.close()
openFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

`("insert into myTable(col1, col2) values(?,?)", [value1, value2])`

So in each row, you would extract the data form the cdv row, and insert the values into your table

Comment: this is the line `values.append('(' + ','.join(map(lambda x: '"%s"' % x, row)) + ')')` in my code that prints `VALUES ("0001","  "," ","`

Comment: What do you need to do? Extract from csv, and insert it into a sql database? If so, you have to make a connexion with the database first

Comment: basically Im doing is  Read the csv file, iterate all the rows in the csv file, generate a insert statement of each row (each row needs to have its insert statement), And output that into a file (.txt file)

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want to do is read in the data from a source CSV and then write out corresponding `INSERT` SQL statements to a file, so that you can pass that directly to your DBMS.

Some of the current issues with your code are:

- Your use of `values.append` will build up the values from each row of the CSV -- so each tuple you insert will contain all the previous tuple's data as well which is not what you want
- You need to write to the output file in each iteration; the current code seems to only write the last row of the CSV file (or perhaps the indentation in the question is wrong)
- Assuming the indentation in the question is wrong, you don't want to be opening & closing the file every time, you only need to open the file once at the start & close it at the very end
- Your output lines should contain a trailing `;` -- to terminate each SQL statement
- Your output lines should also contain a newline for readability

Fixing the above problems, your code becomes roughly the following:

```
import csv

openFile = open('data.csv', 'r')
csvFile = csv.reader(openFile)

headers = [f'"{x}"' for x in next(csvFile)]
insert = f'INSERT INTO my_table ({", ".join(headers)}) VALUES '

createOnFile = open('data.txt', 'w+')

for row in csvFile:
    values = ', '.join([f'"{x}"' for x in row])
    data = insert + ''.join(f'({values});\n')
    createOnFile.write(data)

createOnFile.close()
openFile.close()
```

Note I've also adapted the code to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) instead of string concatenation & also switched the use of `map` to [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which are more succinct in this case.

Comment: nice solution. thank you. However, when I get my `data.txt` output and paste it into microsoft sql manager to run the query. I get an error saying `invalid column name 0.00(which is my column name)`

Comment: Maybe your input isn't as expected. The header line of your CSV contains the column names, right? In that case, they need to be valid for the DBMS you're using - in this case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/column-name-limitations?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: correct. It output `insert into...` for all my columns.  see the output in my code above

Comment: and what did you mean my input isn't as expected

Comment: I mean, does the input CSV file contain a header line as you expect? Since it should contain the names of valid columns. But if its showing "0.00" as one of the column names, then maybe its missing the header line?

Comment: yes it does have a header line in my csv input.

Comment: my column for "0.00" has a header line already in the csv